# How to get the selected cursor position in EditText?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-edittext

There is an `EditText`, what I want is when I select it ,I should get the cursor position. The maximum length of the edittext is 13.

Also in my edittext, the first three character's type is **text** and the other character's  type is **number**. If the first three characters are selected, the input type of keyboard should show **text**. And if any other characters are selected ,then the input type should be **number**. How to do this?

Comment: What did you try so far? Share your efforts

Comment: I tried but I don't want to do this. Did you understand question?

Comment: @InsaneCat it is not duplicate at all. Read question again.

Comment: You need to set `EditText` `inputType` based on what user is typing?

Comment: Yes, I need to set EditText inputType based. But the first three character's type is text and the other character's type is number

Comment: @Raj Thank you for helping me. I have already solved my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this code can help you ❤ :

**Class** Code :

```java
edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtxt);
        edittext.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
        edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(final CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {             

                if (edittext.getText().length() < 3 ) {
                edittext.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);       
                }   
                else if (edittext.getText().length() == 3 ) {
                edittext.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
                }}
                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                }
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                }


    });}}
```

**Xml** Code :

```xml
<EditText
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:maxLength="13"
        android:id="@+id/edtxt"
        android:ems="10"/>
```

Comment: I used addTextChangedListener but I did another with way